# Bash: pass batches of files to python script

Tags: command-line, arguments

I have a python script that takes a path where a bunch of text files are located to process them somehow. Since there are too many files I want to use batches using a bash script to pass just some of the files on the path, say 100 at a time. Is there a simple way to do this. So for example my scripts is currently

```
python application.py -fp [path to all files]
```

Can I do a bash script where I do something like

```
python application.py -fp [file-1:file-100]
```

and on the next loop

```
python application.py -fp [file-101:file-200]
```

and so on?

Edit:

I tried Stephane solution with bash and I think it almost works but I'm still having trouble getting just a subset of the files

I do this to get the path from the parameters given to the bash script

```
set -- "$fp*.txt"
echo "${@}"
```

the result is

```
../../files_test/pair/*.txt
```

which is correct since that is the path of the files I need to get. But then I do

```
files=${@:1:2}
echo $files
```

just to test if I can get the first file but it echos the list of all files in the directory. Am I missing something?

Edit 2:

Nevermind. I realized I was doing

```
set -- "$fp*.txt"
```

instead of

```
set -- $fp*.txt
```

Now it works.

Comment: You'd probably want `set -- "$fp"/*.txt`. That is make sure `$fp` is quoted and `*` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `xargs` and a shell with process substitution support (ksh, bash, zsh), you can do:

```
xargs -r0 -n100 -a <(printf '%s\0' ./*) python application.py -fp
```

Example:

```
$ xargs -r0n4 -a <(printf '%s\0' {1..20}) echo
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20
```

Without process substitution, you can also do:

```
printf '%s\0' ./* | xargs -r0 -n100 -python application.py -fp
```

But that means `application.py`'s stdin will be `/dev/null` which on systems with `/dev/fd/xxx` you can work around by basically implementing process substitution by hand with:

```
{
  printf '%s\0' ./* |
    xargs -a /dev/fd/3 3<&0 <&4 4<&- -r0 -n100 -python application.py -fp
} 4<&0
```

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zargs
zargs -l 100 ./* -- python application.py -fp
```

Example:

```
$ zargs -l4 {1..20} -- echo
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20
```

You can also always do (ksh93/bash/zsh):

```
set -- ./*
while (($# > 0)); do
  python application.py -fp "${@:1:100}"
  shift "$(($# >= 100 ? 100 : $#))"
done
```

Example:

```
$ set -- {1..20};while (($#>0));do echo "${@:1:4}";shift "$(($#>4?4:$#))";done
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20
```

If your files are actually called `file-1`, `file-2`... you'll probably want to use `zsh` and its `n` (for numeric sorting) glob qualifier for the list of files to be sorted numerically:

```
zargs -l 100 ./*(n) -- python application.py -fp
```

Or use GNU `sort -zV` (for version sort) on the output of `printf '%s\0'`:

```
xargs -r0 -n100 -a <(printf '%s\0' ./* | sort -zV) python application.py -fp
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this very complete answer. I tried the one for bash since I can't assure the shell will have process substitution support but it's not working as expected. Can you look into the edit and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Atirag, bash does support process substitution. Process substitution and `((...))` are both ksh features copied by bash.  While `${@:offset:length}` is a ksh93 feature also copied by bash. Of the 3 features, the latter is the least portable (outside of ksh93/zsh/bash).

Comment: oh that's good to know. Thank you. So maybe I'll adapt it to other solution